# Writing an incrementing counter for aspx page c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, counter

I am working on an confirmation system, that sends a number back to the user after the process has been complete.  What I need is a incrementing counter, that send back the new number.  This is what I have so far.

```
int i = 100;
int Counter = i++;

w.Write(Count);
```

I want the counter to start at 100, and when the first user uses the system their count number printed to the screen will be 101.  The second user will be 102... and so on.

I can get it to increment but the only that displays is 101, it doesn't save 101 and increment it to 102.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save counter into [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application.aspx) vault:

```
// read data
// if no such one is present, set counter to the default value (100, etc)
int count = Application["counter"] as int? ?? 100;

// increment
count++;

// save back
Application["counter"] = count;

// do stuff you want to measure
```

But this data will be lost if application dies by timeout, or another reason why the appropriate app pool becomes recycled.

Thus consider to use a database. Install local SQL Express is quite simple task.

---

Also there is another thing to consider: if work fails, do you want to count it in?

```
try
{
    DoWork();
    Count(); // count only if success
}
finally
{
    Count(); // count it anyway
}
```

Comment: I tried you first example and it did not work... Not sure exactly, but could you explain the "? ??" portion and how it relates in C#, thank you.

Comment: @user630581: `int?` means `int which can be null`; operator `a ?? b` means `if a not null then a, otherwise b`; `Application["counter"] as int? ?? 100;` means `if value returned from app vault is int? then use it, otherwise use 100`. Am I clear? Feel free to answer more

Comment: so does Application["counter"] as int? ?? 100; mean that if the value is null, to return null?  I have tried it, and still am having trouble getting it to work.  The issue I run into is that "counter" gets written in the document, instead of a number.

Comment: @user630581: if `Application["counter"]` returns null (nothing was saved before), then `int count` becomes 100 (default value), otherwise - the value stored inside. Don't write counter into response, write only in application[].

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in the asp Application object or in a database. Each request is inherently stateless so you can't keep a variable in scope without sessions or databases.

```
var number = Application["NameOfObject"] as int ?? 100;

number ++;
Application["NameOfObject"] = number;

w.write(number);
```

Answer (score -2):

Web apps are stateless so all data is lost on a page reload. Session state will save the data in memory :

```
Session("counter") = i++;
```

But note that a Session state is per user (so each user will have different counts).

To have sitewide data persist over different sessions and long term the only real solution is to store hits in the database since Application data is cleared on a reload of the app (which will happen if there are no users or if there is a change to web.config)

Comment: You can store it in the Application object

Comment: Aren't all application,session,cache objects stored in memory...? Thats why we test for their existence on app start. How to persist them without a database?

Comment: Save in external file, e.g. XML ~/App_Data/foo.xml

Comment: The question didn't mention persistence, but it did mention that the number needs to increment for all users so the application object makes sense here.

Comment: ok Ken, its a page hit counter. Not much point for this to reset a strange intervals (ie when apps recycles).